# Material Search Bar isn't showing in the layout preview

Tags: android, android-layout

Good Morning

Just want to ask why the layout of my Material Search bar now showing in the layout here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ProductView">


<com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
    style="@style/MaterialSearchBarDark"
    app:mt_speechMode="true"
    app:mt_hint="Custom hint"
    app:mt_maxSuggestionsCount="10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchBar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are the screenshots of what the layout looks like:

[image: Screenshot of LAyout]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the third party library used element which is may not present in your project. 
In your case it should be `constraintlayout`

I just added

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

and the view is visible for me. But its not necessary for your project if you are not using it in other areas.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi i tried your suggestion but @Jinn Still its not visible to me. how should i do?

Comment: the library uses Card view also. try implementing cardview also. then rebuild the project.

Comment: But i suggest not to use unwanted implementation just to view the layout because it will increase the app size.

Comment: implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'